# Add text to a JS countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to hide a DIV after a 10 seconds countdown. It works great but for the moment it only displays 10,9,8, etc. What should I modify in order to add plain text like this "This box will be closed in (10, 9, 8, etc) seconds"
Many thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/QhLcR/

```
<div id="news-container" style="border:5px solid black;width:100%; background: red;">dfdf

<div id="countdown" style="border:1px solid black;width:120px;float: right;">test</div></div>


var time = 10;

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test()
{
             time -=1;
    $('#countdown').html(time); 

if(time == 0)        
{

    $('#news-container').remove();
}
}
```

Comment: erm.... `$('#countdown').html('This box will be closed in ' + time + ' seconds.')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this? http://jsfiddle.net/QhLcR/1/

```
var time = 10;

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test() {
    time -= 1;
    $('#countdown').html('This box will be closed in ' + time + ' seconds');

    if (time == 0) {

        $('#news-container').remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Div has been resized and text has been added

```
<div id="news-container" style="border:5px solid black;width:100%; background: red;">dfdf

<div id="countdown" style="border:1px solid black;width:220px;float: right;">test</div></div>


var time = 10;

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test() {
time -= 1;
$('#countdown').html('This box will be closed in ' + time + ' second(s)');

         if (time == 0) 
         {

              $('#news-container').remove();
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="news-container" style="border:5px solid black;width:100%; background: red;">dfdf

<div id="countdown" style="border:1px solid black;width:120px;float: right;">test</div></div>


var time = 10;

window.setInterval(test, 1000);

function test()
{
             time -=1;
    $('#countdown').html("The box will close in "+time+" seconds!"); 

if(time == 0)        
{

    $('#news-container').remove();
}
}
```